# Метки с описанием и картинкой на Yandex Maps. Как такое реализовать?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, yandex-maps-api

Хочу реализовать форму в которую пользователи вводят название, адрес, широту, долготу, и что важно прикрепляют фото к ней и оно отображается меткой на карте по координатам и названием с *фото*.

В итоге получается что-то вроде [такого](https://prnt.sc/jfyulo), но яндекс карты.

Так же как сделать возможность чтобы все добавленные метки сохранялись по приложению?

Comment: Я думаю это нужно в API Yandex  покопаться.

Answer (score 1):

**Добавление метки на карту**

Чтобы добавить метку на карту необходимо передать в конструктор класса YMaps.Placemark координаты точки ее привязки и список параметров, а затем с помощью метода карты `addOverlay()` добавить метку на карту.

```
// Создает метку в центре Москвы
var placemark = new YMaps.Placemark(new YMaps.GeoPoint(37.609218,55.753559));

// Устанавливает содержимое балуна
placemark.name = "Москва";
placemark.description = "Столица Российской Федерации";

// Добавляет метку на карту
map.addOverlay(placemark);
```

Когда метка открывает балун, ее значок скрывается. Для того, чтобы значок метки оставался на карте, установите опцию `hideIcon` в значение `false`:

```
/ Создает метку, значок которой не скрывается при открытии балуна
var placemark = new YMaps.Placemark(new YMaps.GeoPoint(37.609218,55.753559), {hideIcon: false});

// Добавляет метку на карту
map.addOverlay(placemark);
```

[Ссылка](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/dg/tasks/how-to-add-placemark-docpage/) в Yandex map API.

Comment: Я в самом начале написал - нужно чтоб с фото.
Второе, у вас старый api 1.х
Третье, как сохранить все в приложении

Comment: У меня не старый API :) я просто поискал инфу и дал вам, я уверен там можно передать фото параметром.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере просто задан контент балуна метки.  Это делается через редактирование контента балуна, в котором можно использовать HTML разметку. [Вот пример.](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_balloon?from=SO)

```
var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
    balloonContentBody: [
        '<address>',
        '<strong>Офис Яндекса в Москве</strong>',
        '<br/>',
        'Адрес: 119021, Москва, ул. Льва Толстого, 16',
        '<br/>',
        'Подробнее: <a href="https://company.yandex.ru/">https://company.yandex.ru</a>',
        '</address>'
    ].join('')
}, {
    preset: 'islands#redDotIcon'
});
```

Создать метку с кастомным изображением можно с помощью собственного макета или задав изображение через опции. [Есть пример в документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/icon_customImage?from=SO).

```
myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
        hintContent: 'Собственный значок метки',
        balloonContent: 'Это красивая метка'
    }, {
        // Опции.
        // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        // Своё изображение иконки метки.
        iconImageHref: 'images/myIcon.gif',
        // Размеры метки.
        iconImageSize: [30, 42],
        // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
        // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
        iconImageOffset: [-5, -38]
    })
```

Comment: Как все сохранять в приложении, чтоб все добавленные оставались на карте?